# How can I host my server while on VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am currently hosting a Teamspeak server at home. I intend to have that server connected to a VPN at all times. However, when connected to the VPN, no-one can connect to the Teamspeak server. The VPN service I am using is Private Internet Access which offers port forwarding on certain servers. However, this method will not work for me as my choice of VPN servers is limited.

How can I route the traffic of the Teamspeak server so that it will work when connected to VPN?

Thanks!

Edit: I am using Private Internet Access. To connect, I use their application, but also able to use OpenVPN.

Comment: How would users connect to that Teamspeak Server? How is the VPN related to Teamspeak?

Comment: The problem is that I want users to connect while my server is connected to VPN

Comment: Please edit your question to include details on how you connect to your VPN provider, ie. which software is involved, what protocol is used and where you got the settings from.

Comment: Get in touch with the Support of Private Internet Access, and ask them for a VPN server that sets up a non-compulsory tunnel, meaning does not lock-out all other network interfaces.

Comment: @harrymc Can anything be done on my end?

Comment: The only solution I know of (and use) is to use the VPN inside a virtual machine, so that only the VM is affected. But I don't know if the other computers on your local network are also supposed to use the VPN thru the Teamspeak server. I suggest using OpenVPN instead of their client (the client might do the blocking), and if on Windows, add to your post the output of `route -n` before and after connecting to the VPN. The idea is to use [Split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) to overcome it.

Comment: Pls post your routing table when you are connected via the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

**If port forwarding is possible**

From the information you've shared, it sounds like they may be handing you a dynamic IP or some sort of configuration that is ever changing. Although PIA supports port forwarding as you've said, that doesn't help if the users do not know where the server lives (your VPN IP address).

In this scenario, simply have UDP 9987 forwarded as usual, but you may want to use a dynamic IP service such as No-IP. They have clients that can update the DNS entry yourhost.no-ip.tld from your machine that is running the VPN and Teamspeak 3 server.

On a side-note, to eliminate any strange behavior it would be generally advised to use the OpenVPN client if possible. This permits you to see what kind of configuration they are enforcing to a reasonable extent.

**If port forwarding is truly not possible**

You might be SOL for running this *through* this particular VPN service, as from what I've been able to uncover, their system to permit port forwarding is very strange and hit-and-miss from user experiences.

There are potentially options for getting this to work still, such as inquiring with PIA as to whether or not they permit split-tunneling, for which some data can go through the VPN interface, while others go out your hardware/normally expected interface.

Despite these potential workarounds, I would highly recommend simply using a VPN provider that actually supports port forwarding without a huge hassle to save yourself from this headache. I personally have used nVpn.net in the past, which permits port forwarding (with no hassle!) despite handing out dynamic IPs.

Resources:
user experiences 
https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/1vx0gk/linux_pia_torrents_port_forwarding/
reasonable vpn provider for hosting
https://www.nvpn.net
suggested dynamic DNS (DDNS) provider
https://www.noip.com/
general information & vendors for DDNS
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS

Answer (score 0):

The website for your VPN service says that it acts at the "TCP/IP interface level" so it affects **all** applications.  That would include your TeamSpeak server.

The fact that your users can't connect implies that TeamSpeak clients connect directly to the server, and NOT through an intermediary server in the cloud.

The fact that Private Internet Access even *offers* a port forwarding option implies that it shares IP addresses between clients.  Unfortunately that means that a dynamic IP service like No-IP still wouldn't work.

It seems you have two options, neither one being exactly what you're asking for:

1. Replace Your VPN Service - either find one that allows you to use port forwarding, or find one that provides dedicated IP's to each client (which would negate the need for forwarding in the VPN service, and )
2. Split Your Servers - move either your VPN connection OR the TeamSpeak service to another server.  You could do this physically, or using virtual machine(s) on your existing server.